# Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting the errors:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'DashboardActivity'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and

```
[2013-09-02 17:55:31 - DashboardActivity] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
```

and

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    UserFunctions.java  /DashboardActivity/src/libary   line 1  Java Problem
```

and

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for    java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project DashboardActivity       Unknown Java Problem
```

I have already tried cleaning the project and I get the same errors. Only the 'DashboardActivity' project is the one getting this error and my other projects work fine. In my properties Order and Export section there is a part that says "Unable to get system libary for this project"
I know there should be a proper android.jar file here but I don't see one.

Also, the android tools 'fix project properties' does nothing at all when I click on it.

I have the AndroidManifest.xml file as well.

Ever since I first went to clean my project it has created the file "proguard-project.txt" as well.

What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

NOTE: now I can't acess the gen folder or bin folder (there is no little + for me to click on to open it) and now it's saying that R cannot be resolved to a variable) ???

[image]

### Error while applying

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do this

### Right click on Project Root folder > properties > Java BuildPath > Library Tab

[image]

Check whether any of library is missing (showing error with red cross)
if yes then add this library to your project
don't forget to CHECK it on **Order and Export**

Do one more thing

### Right click on Project Root folder > properties > Android > set your Project Build Target

[image: Project build target]

check any one target

Check your Android-sdk path from

### Window > Preference > Android

[image: Androd-sdk folder]

Comment: I have all of the libaries that I need checked in Order and Export except for the "unable to get system libary for this project"

Comment: Here is my java path:
Source:
DashboardActivity/gen
DashboardActivity/src

Libarires:
android.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES

Comment: I check it and hit OK but when I go back into it it says that it could not accept the changes and the box becomes blank again

Comment: It also says that "The current page contains invalid values" whenever I try to switch from one thing to the next

Comment: It is unable to import Android libraries so unable to build and so R.java is not being created

Comment: you can paste image link by uploading some where on web

Comment: delete unable to get and do the second thing i mentioned

Comment: I deleted it but now when I do the second thing I get a message (see here:http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qvy5tt&s=5) and it makes it so that the box stays unchecked

Comment: have you imported this project from some where else or copy paste

Comment: Press 'apply' then 'ok'

Comment: Not that I know of. Before today my project worked just fine but when I went to clean it today (before I made any changes to clean up any possible R value errors) it said the errors above

Comment: check your android sdk path is there any error  cause now it is unable to access core android library files

Comment: Not that I can see of...by the sdk path you mean where it is placed on my computer correct? (just to make sure)

Comment: sdk path means where your android-sdk folder is placed in your computer check it from Window > Preference > Android

Comment: then copy your project take backup > delete this > import it again > check java build path > android target

Comment: Where exactly do I take backup..?

Comment: just create a copy of project folder thats the backup

Comment: I deleted the project folder after copying it and that was the import screen

Comment: then there is only one method to get rid off just create a new Project and import file system of one by one files to project and take caution if any error occur in between

Comment: Uhh..so I was able to get it into the Workspace again but now all my coding is gone and only the files and their names appear..

Comment: Can I get a honest opinion? Should I just start over again from scratch? :/

Comment: you are in great trouble with this project this time its showing problem with your manifest i would suggest create a new workspace and also have you recently updated your ADT(Android Development Tool)

Comment: that's your ADT plugin have you updated your eclipse ADT plugin to some newer version

Comment: It should be updated to the latest version considering I downloaded eclipse and the whole package about 2 weeks ago

Comment: hmmmm then the only way start from scratch import files and code to it and mind it create new workspace may be it may cause of previous problem

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I want to create a new workspace since my other Android Application Projects work just fine, it's just the DashboardActivity project that gives me problems. Should I just delete the DashboardActivity project from my workspace and start over?

Comment: Alright...thank you for your help anyways through all of this, at least now I know what I am doing better than I did before this experience...Have a good day :)

Comment: My father helped me to restore my entire project back to a save from yesterday through Windows..I can't use Package Explorer on it (which is fine since I'll use just regular folder searching in my workspace) but at least now I can start from there.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having these errors:

> > The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for    java.lang.Object.

and

> > The Project Properties Order and Export section has an error "Unable to get system library for this project"

I solved it by Right Clicking on the Project Root folder > properties > Android > set your Project Build Target and changed it to the highest target I could trust from working on other projects.

It has been 3 years since I had this project working.  So I noticed when I was troubleshooting tonight, that the manifest did not have a targetSdkVersion, only a minSdkVersion of "8".  So I had changed that to this:

After doing the above 2 things, all my errors were gone -- however (!) ... a bit later tonight, I was trying to export my project to an .apk. And Eclipse crashed.  Upon re-opening it, Eclipse is super broken. I am about to do a re-boot my PC now - and thus need to finish posting this.  I trust Eclipse will be back to normal.  But the reason I am mentioning this is that I suspect I may need to re-install Eclipse as I have been getting other minor start-up errors when I open Eclipse. And the errors I had tonight in that app were very strange and unusual.