# Unable to get System Libraries and an empty android project created in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Unable to create an android project in Eclipse Luna using adt 23.0.2

1. Getting Error :

   [2014-09-09 11:01:04 - newapp] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

I am getting error while creating Android project in Eclipse.

[image]

2. When I am checking the project properties I am getting the following Error.

[image]

I have already tried the below links:

[Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582262/project-has-no-project-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one-e)

[Update Eclipse with Android development tools v. 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23)

https://github.com/JPMoresmau/eclipsefp/issues/162

I have also tried click on project -->Android Tools-->Fix Project Properties quick fix.

Comment: are you importing an existing project? or creating one?

Comment: No. I am creating the new one

Comment: have you tried click on project -->Android Tools-->Fix Project Properties quick fix? this seems to be a bug

Comment: Yes i have tried this.

Comment: @kanikaMahajan can you please write down the steps to create new project in eclipse?

Comment: File-->New-->Android Application Project-->Application Name--> Selecting min. and target SDK-->Next-->Blank Activity-->Activity-Name-->Finish